# How can I save my laptop's screen brightness in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: screen, brightness

My laptop's screen brightness returns to the high mode when I restart my computer. 
I wanna to find a method to save it forever. I like change my screen brightness to 40% and save it to prevent its return to high mode(100%) in every restart.

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303088/screen-brightness-reduction-software/303093#303093), see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can fix this issue following the link below,
http://xchamitha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/set-screen-brightness-when-booting.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.