# After installing fglrx on Ubuntu 14.04 there is no backlight (hd 5470). Is there any workaround?

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, backlight

I've installed fglrx driver on my Asus k52je laptop with mobility radeon hd 5470 using additional drivers window in ubuntu. I get black screen after reboot. When I hold power button i can barely see shutdown, restart, lock and suspend icons and I am able to choose one. I've also tried building driver from sources and installing from xorg-edgers. None of those worked. Is there any workaround?

EDIT:

It seems I can use external monitor without issues

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `acpi_backlight=legacy` or `acpi_backlight=vendor` (not both) as a kernel parameter.

If it doesn't help, you could look into this [Wiki-Article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: These kernel parameters (plus acpi_osi=linux) helpded me to get backlight keys working on a new laptop running opensuse 13.1. The problem is, that the screen is completely off after reboot with fglrx installed.
Shady image with just backlight off appears when you boot into rescue mode and select the failsafe graphics option. (I have the same laptop model and the same problem)

Comment: But he says that he can barely see shutdown, restart, lock and suspend buttons. That means, the screen isn't totally black, right? Sounds like a backlighting issue to me. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Let's wait for comments. Anyway, thanks for that hint. I've completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/462336/edit) your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material..

Answer (score 0):

Try

1.

`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`, then

> xbacklight -set xx

(0-100 as far as I remember)

2.

Updating ATI driver to the newest [>>HERE<<](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-14-4-graphics-driver-in-linux.html)

3.

Downgrade fglrx to 13.1 (Reported to work several times in similar cases)

Comment: Yes - the command is xbacklight - you can find some infos in this link of mine too - http://askubuntu.com/questions/318629/lcd-backlight-keys-on-fujitsu-siemens-amilo-pro/319594#319594

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing the driver from the AMD website itself, I suppose. I will tell you how to do that below :-

1. Update your OS completely.
2. Go to [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) website.
3. Now select the appropriate options there. Note that you must select `Linux x86_64` for 64 bit OS and `Linux x86` for 32 bit OS.
4. Now if you proceed by selectin 'Display results' there you will find your drivers.
5. Before you begin downloading **check the release notes and installer notes without fail**. See if your system meets all the system requirements mentioned.(This way we can know if any of your system requirements are not met and then start answering according to that too. Added advantage for you, you know!) To check the system requirements, use the following commands:-

   uname -a    - To know your kernel version
   ldd --version   - To know your eglibc version
   Xorg -version   - To know your Xorg version
6. Now if all those requirements are met then proceed to downloading the driver.
7. Then follow the installer notes for successful installation.

PS:-

- Don't think that your OS isn't supported by the driver just because the OS is not mentioned in the release notes of the driver! If you meet the system requirements its fine.
- Also don't worry if your driver installer shows up like this without any text! :-

[image]

Just see the screen shots given in the installer notes, click accordingly and you can install.

- And don't forget to edit your question if any system requirement is not met or even if all are met but you can't make it work properly. Users will answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes my system meets those requirements. In fact driver is working and if I connect external monitor it works without issues. IThere is just no backlight on my laptop display.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the shutdown or restart other options it means the drivers installed properly but they also reduced your LCD brightness(not the brightness value in system settings)

open terminal and run the below command

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9
```

Its range 0.0(lowest) to 1.0(highest)

Here is another command that changes the display brightness value

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx
```

Where xx is the desired brightness in hexadecimal ranging from 00 (brightest) to FF (no brightness at all).

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing to try that usually fixes this. Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favourite editor and find the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. Insert the following within the double quotes:

`acpi_backlight=vendor`

and run : `sudo-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Changes take place on reboot.