# How to make FN keys change brightness on Gateway m7315u?

Tags: laptop, brightness, gateway

I know this not a new issue concerning brightness, however, I am anxious to get this working. I added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the boot parameters which allows me to change the  brightness using brightness and lock but the fn + up and fn + down just turns the screen off forcing me to close the lid and reopen.

I feel like the only thing I need to do is change some values somewhere to allow these keys to change in increments, but i am not sure how. I have read of some scripts some people have wrote for other laptops, but I have not tried with mine for fear it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this way:

step 1: terminal `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

step 2: modify your file at line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" like that: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=\"Windows 2012\""

step 3: terminal `sudo update-grub`

step 4: reboot

Worked for me on Asus X501A running Ubuntu 13.04 (same problem with fn keys)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/323845/22949). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to the differences in the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was hoping this would finally be the solution but it does not work for me, unless I have done something wrong. I added a "!" before windows 2012 also and that did not work either. I also removed the acpi_backlight=vendor and tried it like that too and it did not work. I am open to any more suggestions, and thank you for your response!